# Stopwatch display issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nstimer, stopwatch

I have compiled the following code and there are no apparent runtime errors; however, the display freezes at 00:00:01 when I run it. It works if I only display the seconds attribute. Does anyone see an apparent oversight that I have missed in this code? I know there is a potential memory leak with the start button, but I will fix that eventually.

Thanks in advance.

```
#import "StopwatchViewController.h"

@implementation StopwatchViewController

- (IBAction)start{

    //creates and fires timer every second
    myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];
}
- (IBAction)stop{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)reset{

    [myTimer invalidate];
    time.text = @"00:00:00";
}

(void)showTime{

    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];

    int new = currentTime +1;

    int secs  = new;
    int mins  = (secs/60) % 60;
    int hours = (mins/60);

    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",hours, mins, secs];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting 0 from

```
int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
```

because the string that's in `text`:

```
@"00:00:00"
```

can't be converted to an `int`, so every time the timer fires, you add 1 to 0 and get 1, which you then display. The math would be inaccurate anyways, because minutes and seconds are "base-60"* -- you'd need to do the reverse of the math you perform for separating hours/minutes/seconds, in order to get the total seconds again. You could just make `currentTime` an ivar, and keep the total number of seconds in it.

---

*That's not really what it's called; I'm sure there's a specific word for it.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to only keep track of seconds, and then format the display for the text field (instead of using the text field's value as your model data).

Comment: Great thanks for the suggestions. I don't know why I did such bonehead move. I will tinker with it and post the corrected version. Appreciate the help.

Comment: As promised. Thanks again @Josh Caswell and @Wevah for the suggestions. I hope this will help some confused person out there. I created an ivar as per Josh's suggestion and you can see the rest.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)start{

    currentTime = 0;

    //creates and fires timer every second
    myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];
}

- (IBAction)stop{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)reset{

    [myTimer invalidate];
    time.text = @"00:00:00";
}

- (void)showTime{

    currentTime++;

    int secs = currentTime % 60;
    int mins = (currentTime / 60) % 60;
    int hour = (currentTime / 3600);


    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",hour, mins, secs];

}
```